# Copy objects between buckets using aws sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Using AWS CLI; we can copy or sync files directly from one bucket to other. Using SDK; I can see api for download and upload. But can we directly copy files from one bucket to other bucket ( in different aws account) using sdk !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The [`CopyObject`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CopyObject.html) API call can copy an object between Amazon S3 buckets, including bucket in different regions and different accounts.

To copy objects between accounts, the one set of credentials requires sufficient permission to Read from the source bucket and Write to the destination bucket. You can either:

- Use credentials from the **destination account**, and use a Bucket Policy on the **source bucket** to grant Read access, *or*
- Use credentials from the **source account**, and use a Bucket policy on the **destination bucket** to grant Write access. Make sure you set `ACL=public-read` to **pass ownership** of the object to the destination Account.

Please note that it only copies **one object at a time**, so you would need to loop through a list of objects and call `CopyObject` for each one individually if you wish to copy multiple objects.

Comment: Thanks John...This is helpful; I was not aware of this one.  These are  REST API. By any chance do we have any  SDKs in Go  !

Comment: [AWS SDK for Go](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/)

Answer (score 1):

It's easy,  see all the CLI commands with the help:

`aws s3 --help`

Upload a file:

```
aws s3 cp <path-to-file-from-local> s3://<S3_BUCKET_NAME>/<file-name>
```

Download a file:

```
aws s3 cp s3://<S3_BUCKET_NAME>/<file-name> <path-to-file-from-local>
```

Move a file:

```
aws s3 mv s3://<S3_BUCKET_NAME>/<file-name> s3://<S3_BUCKET_NAME>/<file-name>
```

You can use **.** to specify the current directory, eg:

```
aws s3 cp s3://MyBucket/Test.txt .
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question I am aware of this using CLI.

Comment: @DeepakSinghal - sorry I just read *Using AWS CLI; we can copy or sync files directly from one bucket to other.* and immediately started typing. Do Mark John's answer as correct.

Comment: Thanks fine :)  anyway thanks for your time